# Map database table to a Hashtable

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0

I have simple table in Oracle db with the columns : "KEY", "VALUE".
I would like to map this table in my java code as a 
is there anyway of doing this straightly in JPA?  or should I do it manually ?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 2):

If key and value are basic or embedded types then you want to use

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "table")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "KEY")
@Column(name = "VALUE")
protected Map<A,B> map;
```

If they are entites then you want to have a look at the docs for the following, so you can choose which is most appropriate.

```
@OneToMany
@ManyToMany
@MapKey
@MapKeyClass
```

Comment: they key and the value are String. I couldnt find the annotaions you mention above(@elementCollection, CollectionTable..) could you pass please some example?

Comment: @rayman - They are JPA2 annotations (`javax.persistence`). If you only have JPA1 there are vendor-specific alternatives, but otherwise you'll have to fall back to manual mapping (like Pablo's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code:

```
public Map<String, String> getAll() {
    Map<String, String> ret = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Query query = em.createQuery("select kvp from KeyValuePair kvp");
    for (KeyValuePair kvp : query.getResultList())
    {
       ret.put(kvp.getKey(), kvp.getValue());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Do keep in mind that if your table is too big, you might end up having memory issues.

Comment: "for (KeyValuePair kvp : query.getResultList())" the KeyValuePair kvp should be refer as what?

Comment: `KeyValuePair` would be your persisted class that you are populating through JPA.

Answer (score 0):

[Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) has a [DatabaseConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/DatabaseConfiguration.html) class for mapping key value tables to a Java Properties like class.